# I can minimize Form1 but not maximized when clicking on task bar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

1-Open any window in the your computer.

2-Minimize that window.

3-Click minimized window below on task bar and see that your window is maximized again.

I have written windows form application program using vb.net language.

I am able to minimize Form1 using following code;

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

I need a vb.net code which makes minimized window maximized when clicking it on the task bar.

In other words, I can minimize Form1 but not maximized when clicking on task bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `your window is maximized again` on mine they are *restored*.  They only `Maximize` if they were maximized before being sent to the taskbar.

Comment: The proper term is "Restored", "Maximized" is  the state where the window fills the screen.  This is a function of windows and not your VB code, in fact unless you do a lot of "low-level" coding you have no control over this and this will continue to function even if your application was hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that and see if that will work. When you restore a window from the taskbar it is restored to the state it was in before it was minimized. Setting your window to a maximized state before you minimize it should make it maximized when you bring it back up.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub
```

Comment: I asked this question wrong way. Please delete your answer in order to I am able to delete whole topic. I will ask this question again in right way.

Comment: No, will not delete my answer. Please refer to here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258745/what-should-i-do-when-op-ask-me-to-delete-my-answer